# Having date range filter in GridMvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, grid.mvc

My requirement is to have date range filter in one of the date type column in `Grid.Mvc` plugin, As of now I am able to apply filter on single date picker control with *"Equal", "Greater Than"* and *"Less Than"* options.

[image: Ref: Image]

But my requirement is to have *"Between"* clause and set of two date picker controls from where user can select *"From Date" and "To Date"*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code to get better answer. Considering mvc-grid documentation, you need to use `MultiFiltering`, and if you want to modify the appearance then you need to define a custom filter.

Here is links to documentation: [MultiFiltering](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/MultiFiltering), [Custom Filtering](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Column/CustomFilter)

If you don't need the custom control and multi-filtering is fine for you:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => model.Registration).Titled("Registration").Filterable(true);    
        columns.Add(model => model.Details).Titled("Details").MultiFilterable(true);
})
)
```

If you need to create a custom filtering take a look at [Filter Registration](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Filter/Register)